# Prove that both $4m^2+17n^2$ and $4n^2+17m^2$ cannot be perfect squares for positive integers $m$ and $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that both $4m^2+17n^2$ and $4n^2+17m^2$ cannot be perfect squares for positive integers $m$ and $n$.

I tried square bounding but didn't get very far.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: Because I have tried many cases and found an upper bound (after some WLOG arguments). Mainly though, because it was given to me in a problem handout.

Comment: Oh, good. Problem handout from whom, in what course or situation?

Comment: From my Olympiad maths tutor (high school) who give me problem sheets to work through in number theory, geometry etc. Normally I refer to him for help every week when I see him, but he was hurt in a car accident recently so I came here as this problem got the better of me.

Comment: Alright, getting a little clearer. What methods have you been working with that might relate to this?

Comment: Modulo, but as far as I can see they are fairly useless here, bounding arguments (square bounding I think here - no calculus), WLOG etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main thing about the sum of two squares is that, for any (positive) prime $$ q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$$  if
$$ q | (x^2 + y^2)  $$ then actually $$ q|x,y $$ both. By induction, we get $$ q^{2k} \parallel (x^2 + y^2),  $$ where this notation means that $ q^{2k} | (x^2 + y^2)  $ but **not** $ q^{2k +1} | (x^2 + y^2)  .$ The notation is used only when the left hand side is a prime, otherwise it becomes ambiguous; it is a handy shorthand, though.

In your problem statement, add the two together, you get
$$ 21 (m^2 + n^2) = x^2 + y^2.  $$ This is a contradiction, as 3 now divides the right hand side by an odd power. Same for 7.

Given any quadratic form $$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, $$ abbreviated as $$ \langle a,b,c \rangle $$ the discriminant is $$   \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c.$$ For positive forms this is negative. For indefinite forms, this is positive. We discard the case when $\Delta$ is $0$ or a (positive) square, as those forms factor.

For any (positive) odd prime $q$ with Legendre symbol $(\Delta | q) = -1,$ then, whenever $q$ divides $  a x^2 + b x y + c y^2, $ it follows that $$ q^{2k} \parallel (  a x^2 + b x y + c y^2).  $$ Worth proving yourself, in full detail. Caution: part of the hypothesis is that $\Delta \neq 0 \pmod q.$ That matters. Not sure how much more to say: there are thus two cases, $a \neq 0 \pmod q$ and $a \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ which is actually quite similar because ***_***.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's very nice. I didn't think of doing anything along those lines. I'll remember this for future reference.